# Error installing VMWare workstation 12 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: vmware

I am trying to install vmware workstation 12 on Ubuntu 14.04 and I got following errors.

Please how do I fix this

This is the installation command I used.

```
laura@laura:~$ cd ~/Downloads  
laura@laura:~/Downloads$ sudo chmod +x VMware-Player*.bundle  
[sudo] password for laura:   
laura@laura:~/Downloads$ sudo ./VMware-Player*.bundle  
Extracting VMware Installer...done.    
(vmware-installer.py:3926): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",  
(vmware-installer.py:3926): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",  
(vmware-installer.py:3926): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine", 
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module": libcanberra-gtk-module.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Then after completing the installation process and attempting to run, I get this

[image]

Comment: What one immediately notices is that the device that can't be opened is /dev/vmmon and that the "Virtual machine monitor" doesn't start.  Those are obviously related.  I have never actually installed VMWare Workstation, but have you run the installer using sudo?  Installation of software like this is bound to need root privileges.  The fact that your virtual ethernet fails, is also a hint in that direction.

Comment: I actually run the installer using sudo. It has been on for about 3 years, and suddenly it crashed and gives that message,

Comment: Was worth asking. :-D

Comment: Try to see whether there are log files on why these services fail.  I don't know where vmware log stuff.  Try /var/log/syslog and see if there are vmware.log files in /var/log
Also, next time, try to give the full output of the installation including launched command.  That is much more useful than just half a screenshot.

Comment: Thanks @jawtheshark. I haven't found any log files for the vmware. Maybe I'm not searching right, please guide me on how to. I have also attached new pictures of terminal commands for the installation process.

Comment: Unfortunately I had to delete the other images since I have a max of 2 links.

Comment: Those services need recompiled, have you tried to open VMware Workstation Player since you installed it?  (It should try and build/launch those services)

Comment: Just copy/paste the treminal commands and use formatting "`" to highlight them.  Screenshots are superfluous for textual representation of terminals.

Comment: @Thomas Ward, yes I tried to open it and had the "vmmom" error I shared yesterday.

Comment: `, Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module": libcanberra-gtk-module.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory "`.

I'd say: start off with fixing that. `apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module`

Comment: "laura@laura:~/Downloads$ apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module  
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)  
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?"   I got this output

Answer (score 0):

For this error:

> Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module": libcanberra-gtk-module.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

1. First find out where "libcanberra-gtk-module.so" is,

   > locate libcanberra-gtk-module.so

   This may cause following output:

   > laura@laura:~$ locate libcanberra-gtk-module.so
   >   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/modules/libcanberra-gtk-module.so
   >   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/modules/libcanberra-gtk-module.so

   If didn't find any matched file, install this package:

   > sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module

---

2. Then create two files:

   > sudo touch /etc/ld.so.conf.d/gtk-2.0.conf
   >   sudo touch /etc/ld.so.conf.d/gtk-3.0.conf

   Edit this file:

   > sudo vim /etc/ld.so.conf.d/gtk-2.0.conf

   And insert the location just found **(File path only!)**

   > /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/modules

   For the other file, just add the other location.

---

3. Reload config.

   > sudo ldconfig

---

4. Reinstall VMware

**Note that** if you meet this error:

> locate: can not stat () `/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db': No such file or directory

Please execute:

> updatedb

**Do remember always start vmware as root! (By adding 'sudo' before your command)**
VMware must acquire enough permission to load virtual machine.

Edit the application link so that vmware can take enough permission automatically:

[Example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPR4y.jpg)

Notice this line:

> Exec=gksu -s /usr/bin/vmware %U

Be sure that your file is started with **'gksu -s'**

If you don't have gksu, install:

> sudo apt-get install gksu

---

It's not a simple problem, but I wish this answer can help you.